# Difference between spring.datasource.username and spring.datasource.data-username

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to know the difference between these properties :

```
spring.datasource.username 

spring.datasource.data-username
```

same about:

```
spring.datasource.password

spring.datasource.data-password
```

How and when to use it in the project ?

Comment: See documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following properties are used for authentication against the database:

- `spring.datasource.username`
- `spring.datasource.password`

And the following properties are used for authentication against the database when executing DML scripts (if they are different from the previous properties):

- `spring.datasource.data-username`
- `spring.datasource.data-password`

These properties are described in the [common application properties documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html).